# "zip" a mySQL (phpMyAdmin) database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I've created a large database on my local WAMP webserver.

I would like to send that database with all tables and table data to another computer.

Is this possible?

- mySQL ver: 5.5.15
- PHP ver: 5.3.8
- Apache ver: 2.2.21

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you use phpMyAdmin on your WAMP server, you can use the **Export** tab to dump your database and all the data in it.

On the Export tab, choose the Custom export method. This opens a bunch of options. Under Save Output to a File, choose **Compression** and you get to choose zipped from a drop-down.

Then you can **Import** that zip to another MySQL instance on another computer.

Comment: Zip might not be there if php extension for it is disabled. He can either choose any of the other compression methods or just download an uncompressed file and .zip if manually using `7zip` or any other archiver.

Comment: @edvinas.me, thanks for the clarifications.